# How to create an igraph object from adjacency list with additional information in R?

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-list

I have quite extensive network data in the form

```
df <- data.frame(name= c("Sue", "Rob", "Jacob", "Terry"), 
                 f1 = c("Rob", "Sue", "Rob", "Jacob"), 
                 f2 = c(NA, "Terry", "Terry", NA),
                 f3 = c(NA, "Jacob", NA, NA), 
                 bf1 = c(1,1,1,0), 
                 bf2 = c(NA, 1, 0, NA), 
                 bf3 = c(NA, 0, NA, NA) )
```

where the variables `f1` to `f3` refer to the friends Sue, Rob, Jacob and Terry have. The variables `bf1` to `bf3` refer to whether they see them as a best friend.

I would now like to create a graph item with R `igraph` based on this dataframe and include all information. So far I have:

```
adj_list <- subset(df, select = c(name, f1:f3))
m <- as.matrix(adj_list)
el1 <- cbind(m[, 1], c(m[, -1]))
el1 <- el1[complete.cases(el1),]
el1[2,] <- as.numeric(factor(c(el1[1,])))
g1 <- graph_from_edgelist(el1)
```

But I don't know how to get the secondary information into the graph object. Any ideas?

Comment: try reshape your data to long : `dat <- reshape(df, varying=list(2:4, 5:7), direction="long", idvar="name")` . Tidy it up `ldat <- ldat[!is.na(ldat$f1), -2]`, then read in to igraph `g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(ldat)` : bf is read in as edge attribute.

Comment: I assume you mean the `bf1` through `bf3` as secondary information, right? PS: The edge weights can be accessed via `E(g1)$weight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to reshape your data to long format.

```
# Get indices of columns to group together
friendsIndices <- with(dat, grep("^f", names(dat))) # strings beginning with 'f`
bffIndices <- with(dat, grep("^bf", names(dat))) # strings beginning with 'bf`
```

Reshape

```
ldat <- reshape(dat, 
                varying=list(friendsIndices, bffIndices),
                direction="long", idvar="name")

# Tidy up long data -
  # remove time column
  # remove rows with `NA`
ldat <- ldat[!is.na(ldat$f1), -match("time", names(ldat))]
ldat
#          name    f1 bf1
# Sue.1     Sue   Rob   1
# Rob.1     Rob   Sue   1
# Jacob.1 Jacob   Rob   1
# Terry.1 Terry Jacob   0
# Rob.2     Rob Terry   1
# Jacob.2 Jacob Terry   0
# Rob.3     Rob Jacob   0
```

Data can now be read in to `igraph`

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(ldat)
```

The `bf` attribute is stored as in the edge attribute `E(g)$bf1`.
You can then add edge colours or weights when plotting based on this attribute.

```
plot(g, 
     edge.width=2*(E(g)$bf1+1), 
     edge.color=c("red", "blue")[E(g)$bf1+1],
     edge.curved=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have not thought about reshaping!